# SSH Connection refused after running pkill

Tags: linux, ssh, connection

I have a Linux VPS and I just ran pkill to kill a user because I was not able to do usermod. But after I did that I wasn't able to login anymore on that user, so I googled a bit and saw some posts what said you just have to reboot. Thats what I did but I am still not able to connect, so I went over to my host and decided to restart the server, that didn't work either... I am able to connect via recovery mode but I just don't really know how to fix this.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Your question is not Ubuntu-specific, I think the change would only narrow it without any reason.

Answer (score 2):

Boot your VM, log in via the console and carry out some diagnostics.

I would start by checking to see if sshd is running by using `ps` and (`ss -tnlp` |`netstat -tnlp`). If it's not running check your logs to see if it left any error messages. Check also that it is configured to start when the system boots.

If it is running then I would ensure that I am trying to connect on the correct port with ssh.

I would check that my firewall is not blocking the port that sshd is listening on.

Beyond the above it depends upon what you find as to what you do next.